# Meaning of phrase "returning unit"

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

This is the sentence in which this phrase appears:

> The great Northern cycle of which he is the *returning unit* has almost completed its round, accomplished itself.

("[Herman Melville's Typee and Omoo](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~hyper/lawrence/dhlch10.htm)", Ch. 10 of *Studies in Classic American Literature,* by D.H. Lawrence)

Comment: Google shows this is part of a [D.H. Lawrence essay](http://xroads.virginia.edu/~hyper/lawrence/dhlch10.htm) - it's possible you'll get a better answer in [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), as it appears to be nonstandard poetic language.

Comment: @AlanT.: Nah. It's [Herman Melville](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IHSM6SIGi1AC&pg=PA335&dq=%22great+Northern+cycle+of+which+he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwim7qq85aveAhWtmIsKHfv-AXsQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22great%20Northern%20cycle%20of%20which%20he%22&f=false). I'm guessing this particular "cycle" relates in some way to cyclical invasions / retreats by Vikings in Northern Europe, Wagner's Ring Cycle, Germanic myths like "Siegfried and Brunhilde", etc. But it's all a bit POB for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Erm, yes, it's a D.H. Lawrence essay *about* Herman Melville...

Comment: Fair enough. But I did find this... [Of considerably more intrinsic interest, and not without importance for the study of Romance literature, is the great Northern cycle, the central theme of which, the tragedy of Siegfried and Briinnhilde, has become familiar to the present generation through the medium of Wagner's music-drama, the Ring der Nibelungen.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22become+familiar+to+the+present+generation+through+the+medium+of+Wagner%27s+music-drama%22)

Comment: I will follow your suggestion. As for the Northern cycle, it is somewhat clear what it is, but "returning unit" is the secret to me.

Comment: It appears to me that this "returning unit" should be read as "revenant", but I am not absolutely certain.

Answer (score 2):

Lawrence wrote in the period after the First World War, where hundreds of thousands of men would die in a single battle (e.g.[Somme, 1915](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Somme)).

The term *returning unit* would be used to denote a single unit from a larger formation that survived and returned. A platoon or squad from a regiment maybe, or a battalion from an entire division.

For the readers of that period, *returning unit* would have meant something immediate and personal.

Comment: That is a very useful and interesting elaboration. Thanks!